# Namespace error while importing to oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I'm a newbie in Oracle 12c who is trying to follow [this tutorial](https://blogs.oracle.com/datamining/entry/use_oracle_data_miner_to).

I've create a new connection `orcl/SYSTEM/oracle` and logged in as `SYSTEM/oracle` in SQL developer command line.

The problems is that when I'm trying to import twitter_data.imp from that `demo.zip` file:

```
imp dmuser/dmuser file=twitter_data.dmp log=twitter_data.log full=y
```

It says there's `no "TBS_1" namespace`. How can I globally create this namespace for oracle 12c (in my new connection). I'm kinda thinking about it should be namespace for table (but there's none, right?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're missing a ***`TABLESPACE`***; try the following

```
CREATE TABLESPACE TBS_1 DATAFILE 'TBS_1_dat' SIZE 500K AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 300K MAXSIZE 100M;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Oracle SQL Developer, then go to the database connection you have created and click on Manage Database. You would be provided with the list of all tablespace along with the capacity and free space.

twitter_data.dmp file might have been created on the tablespace "TBS_01". While restoring it will search for the same.

Create the tablespace as below while connecting as SYSDBA -

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbs_perm_02 DATAFILE 'tbs_01.dat' SIZE 500M
```

The path of the dat file to be created is up to you, plus auto-extend and other options you choose freely.